# update the nested fields in json using partial update or update queries

Tags: javascript, elasticsearch

i am using elasticsearch,i want to update specific fields in json using specific key in my case it's macid,the json looks like this

```
{
    macid:"mac1234",
    attri:
        {
            data:{

                ch1:12,
                ch2:123
            },
            settings:
                {
                    log_time:1min

                }


        }

}
```

and i want to update data,settings field with matching macid,and also their will be multiple records

Comment: Can you provide more clarity? Do you have an array of JSON objects like the above? Do you want to provide the same update to all of them? If you have just the single JSON object with the single macid, you'd just use an `if` statement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your JSON has errors, I feel you should cover the strings with quotes.

A good solution to your problem is to transform the JSON to object and then transform the object back to JSON file.

JSON.parse(Json) transform jSON to object while

JSON.stringify transforms object back to JSON

here is a javascript fix:

```
var  jsonT = '{"macid":"mac1234","attri":{"data":{"ch1":12,"ch2":123},"settings":{"log_time":"1min"}}}'

var f = JSON.parse(jsonT);
f.attri.data.ch1 = "hi"

jsonT = JSON.stringify(f);
console.log(jsonT);
```

There are other ways you could do this and then export to .json file

Comment: thanks for your response,but what i want is,let's say i know the macid and i want to update the data array inside attri array.I hope you get it

Comment: @savyaDhurve I have updated the code. All you need to do is to treat the f object like a normal object

Comment: also do you need to to export it a .json file?